# Sending And Read multiple strcuts in C# TCP IP

Tags: c#, struct, tcp, client-server

I want to develop a service that have server which get multiple connection and requesting and read struct based data. Now problem is how to send and receive multiple structs from client and decrypt (or deserialize it for similar data).

It would be really cool to get more help where you can read how to do this in C#

Client code:

```
List<ResponseMessage> messages = new List<ResponseMessage>();

messages.Add
(
    new ResponseMessage()
    {
        cmd = 2,
        cmd_num = 4,
        client_id = 5,
        local_part_num = 1,
        end_buffer_address = 100500,
        group_id = 1
    }
);

messages.Add
(
    new ResponseMessage()
    {
        cmd = 2,
        cmd_num = 24,
        client_id = 11,
        local_part_num = 25,
        end_buffer_address = 300500,
        group_id = 33
    }
);



ResponseMessage message = new ResponseMessage();

using TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

Random rand = new Random();

try
{
    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 8888);

    var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    foreach(var msg in messages)
    {
        var byteArray = StructureToByteArray(msg);

        await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

/// <summary>
/// From structures to byte array
/// </summary>
byte[] StructureToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);

    byte[] arr = new byte[size];

    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);

    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return arr;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 12)]
struct RequestMessage
{
    public sbyte cmd;
    public byte cmd_num;
    public short rsvd;
    public int request_address;
    public int request_size;

    public RequestMessage()
    {
        cmd = 1;
        cmd_num = 200;
        rsvd = 0;
        request_address = 192133333;
        request_size = 350350333;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 12)]
struct ResponseMessage
{
    public sbyte cmd;
    public byte? cmd_num;
    public short? local_part_num;
    public short? group_id;
    public short? client_id;
    public int? end_buffer_address;

    public ResponseMessage()
    {
        cmd = 2;
        cmd_num = 200;
        local_part_num = 1;
        group_id = 1;
        client_id = 4;
        end_buffer_address = 123213123;
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);

try
{

    tcpListener.Start();

    ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage();

    Program p = new Program();

    int ClientCounter = 0;

    while (true)
    {

        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();


        NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        ClientCounter++;

        try
        {
            byte[] responseData = new byte[1024];

            var response = new StringBuilder();

            int bytes = 0;

            StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            do
            {
                bytes = await stream.ReadAsync(responseData);

                responseMessage = FromBytes(responseData);
                 
                responseBuilder.Append($"{responseMessage.cmd} ");
                responseBuilder.Append($"{responseMessage.cmd_num} ");
                responseBuilder.Append($"{responseMessage.local_part_num} ");
                responseBuilder.Append($"{responseMessage.group_id} ");
                responseBuilder.Append($"{responseMessage.client_id} ");
                responseBuilder.Append($"{responseMessage.end_buffer_address}");

                Console.WriteLine(responseBuilder);

            }
            while (bytes > 0);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
    tcpListener.Stop();
}


ResponseMessage FromBytes(byte[] arr)
{
    ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage();

    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(responseMessage);
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);

        var x = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);

        responseMessage = (ResponseMessage)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, responseMessage.GetType());
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
    return responseMessage;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 12)]
struct RequestMessage
{
    public sbyte cmd;
    public byte cmd_num;
    public short rsvd;
    public int request_address;
    public int request_size;

    public RequestMessage()
    {
        cmd = 1;
        cmd_num = 200;
        rsvd = 0;
        request_address = 192133333;
        request_size = 350350333;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to ask this just for the record: Why reinvent the wheel that already has been reinvented a dozen times? ( If the answer is "learning by experiment" answers will be different ;) )

Comment: I've got a task to develop this in c#, first time encountered by network with c#

Comment: If you do not have some special reason why you *have to* use raw TCP, and just want some computers to communicate. Go with some higher level protocol. For example a webservice or gRPC. This will take care of a whole bunch of issues, and will have libraries to do the serialization for you.

Comment: I need to use only TCP to correctly receive and send data to client devices, so now i'm struggling

Comment: So, you have a (well documented) protocol on top of TCP, right? (I.e. the devices expect messages and send messages in specific format)

Comment: Yes, thats it. Device send messages in format ResponseMessage struct and Receive in RequestMessage struct

Comment: Ok, so: If you want to be able to handle more than 1 connection at a time, you need to outsource the handling of each client from accepting the connections. That means: your "main loop" is basically "while not told to shutdown: accept connection => spin off new thread and hand over the connection, loop". Since TCP is bidirectional, you'd usually have a dedicated listener thread, decode messages from there and act upon it. The details can of course be very different depending on application.

Comment: ^^ How to decode of course depends on the protocol in use. Just remember that one result of "Read" does not neccessarily mean that you have a complete message of the protocol. TCP itself is unaware of such protocol, so it's up to you as the implementor of that protocol to detect message boundaries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing TCP/IP applications is extremely difficult. If there's a library or DLL or something that already does the protocol handling for you, then use that.

If you *must* write your own TCP/IP application, then I recommend watching my [video series on asynchronous TCP/IP](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS) as well as reading my [TCP/IP .NET FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html). Then read your device's protocol document. Probably two or three times.

Side note: you probably don't want nullable types in your blittable structs. Personally, I avoid blittable structs these days; you can use `BinaryPrimitives` and friends instead.